# how to sort arraylist object of lowest value?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
ArrayList <ShyForeignStockHolding> aithird = new ArrayList<ShyForeignStockHolding>();

ShyForeignStockHolding shyfrst = new ShyForeignStockHolding (shyPurchaseSharePrice, shyCurrentSharePrice, shyNumberOfShares, shyCompanyName, shyconversionRate1);

aithird.add(shyfrst);
```

I want to sort `ArrayList` by `Currentshare Price`

Comment: shyCurrentSharePrice is float type variable

Comment: You can use a java Comparator to achieve what you want.

Comment: can you give me some hint ??or example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `Comparator` of your Object, assuming that you are using double for the `shyCurrentSharePrice`:

```
List<ShyForeignStockHolding> sFSH = new ArrayList<ShyForeignStockHolding>();
//add Your objects
Collections.sort(sFSH, new Comparator<ShyForeignStockHolding>() {
    @Override public double compare(ShyForeignStockHolding ssh1, ShyForeignStockHolding ssh2) {
        return ssh1.shyCurrentSharePrice + shh2.shyCurrentSharePrice; //descending use - for Ascending
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can now create a Comparator easily like so (avoiding anonymous classes entirely). Since this is in ascending order, you can then call `reversed()` on that Comparator to make it descending.

```
Comparator<ShyForeignStockHolding> comparator = Comparator.comparing((sh -> sh.getTheVarYouWantToCompareBy())).reversed();
aithird.sort(comparator);
```